# Disable single click action on Ctrl Click

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am facing a weird situation. On click i am binding an event which will call an AJAX function, but when i press Ctrl Click the default click action should be disabled. Is there any way i can achieve it.. please share any ideas on how to proceed further..

```
$('#demo1').click(function(e) {
  if(e.ctrlKey  == true) {
    alert("control click");
  } 
  else {
    alert("normal click");
        $("#demo1").bind('select_node.jstree', function(event, data) {
        var url = data.rslt.obj.children("a:eq(0)").attr("href"); 
        $('.ui-layout-center').load(url);
        });
  } 
});
```

Comment: I was able to do it, but jstree bind click is still initiated... see the modified code...

Answer (score 2):

Check `e.ctrlKey`.

Comment: checking only e.ctrlKey wont help, you should check for e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey as metaKey property is set to true if command key is pressed in mac

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey )
{
   /* do your click thing (e.g. open-in-new-window) */
   window.open( $(this).attr('data-url') );
   return;
}
else
{
   /* do your regular thing (e.g. go to another page) */
   window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-url');
}
```

for the bind part, maybe [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/); helps?

And: try a **return false** in the the above code, to prevent events from 'bubbling up'.

Comment: You should also consider the shift key, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25919826/421243)

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely not that familiar (only recently did I start in jquery) but would preventDefault and http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ctrl-click help you at all?

Comment: event.preventDefault or preventPropogation? might help. I will try it out when I get a chance.